# Convert HDF4 to raster; with longitude/latitude grids are available in another HDF file

Tags: r, gis, r-raster, rgdal, hdf

I am trying to convent HDF4 files (representing daily Sea Ice Concentration) to raster object in R. However, the HDF files themselves do not contain the longitude/latitude grids or projection information, and such information should be extracted from another hdf file.

The [website](https://seaice.uni-bremen.de/start/data-archive/) on data format says:

```
Data Format
Sea ice concentration maps with two different color scales are available as PNG image. The NIC color scale uses the same colors as the National Ice Center, the "visual" color scale uses white and shades of grey.
There is one file per day per region per color scale.
Sea ice concentration data are available as HDF4 files: There is one file per day per region. Each file contains one two-dimensional array of the sea ice concentration in a polar stereographic grid.
The longitude and latitude coordinates of each pixel in a the HDF4 file are saved in extra files, one file per region for each available resolution.
They are found here: https://seaice.uni-bremen.de/data/grid_coordinates/,  sorted by hemisphere and grid resolution (see also the README file https://seaice.uni-bremen.de/data/grid_coordinates/README).
GEOTIFF files use the NIC color scale and were tested to work with QGIS. Ice concentrations are scaled between 0 and 100, land and missing values are set to 120 (older files: SIC: 0-200, land/NaN: 255).
```

I tried to use R to load [this map](https://seaice.uni-bremen.de/data/amsre/asi_daygrid_swath/s6250/2003/feb/Antarctic/asi-s6250-20030214-v5_nic.png) using this code:

```
> require(raster)
> CurrTemp <- tempfile()
> download.file(url = "https://seaice.uni-bremen.de/data/amsre/asi_daygrid_swath/s6250/2003/feb/Antarctic/asi-s6250-20030214-v5.hdf", destfile = CurrTemp, mode = "wb", quiet = T)
> Map1 <- readAll(raster(CurrTemp))
> plot(Map1)
> Map1
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1328, 1264, 1678592  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1264, 0, 1328  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : in memory
names       : file43fc5b4e68de 
values      : 0, 100  (min, max)
```

The map is loaded into R as raster object but with wrong coordinates and with no projection. According to [this page](https://seaice.uni-bremen.de/data/grid_coordinates/README), coordinates should be extracted from [another hdf file](https://seaice.uni-bremen.de/data/grid_coordinates/s6250/LongitudeLatitudeGrid-s6250-Antarctic.hdf).

Could you please let me know how to convert these hdf files into raster obejcts with correct coordinates and projection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used one of the geotiff files that they also make available to find the extent and crs.

```
library(raster)
raster('asi-AMSR2-s6250-20180922-v5.tif')
#class       : RasterLayer 
#dimensions  : 1328, 1264, 1678592  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution  : 6250, 6250  (x, y)
#extent      : -3950000, 3950000, -3950000, 4350000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-70 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs 
#data source : asi-AMSR2-s6250-20180922-v5.tif 
#names       : asi.AMSR2.s6250.20180922.v5 
#values      : 0, 255  (min, max)
```

Now I know I can do

```
library(raster)
CurrTemp <- tempfile()
download.file(url = "https://seaice.uni-bremen.de/data/amsre/asi_daygrid_swath/s6250/2003/feb/Antarctic/asi-s6250-20030214-v5.hdf", destfile = CurrTemp, mode = "wb", quiet = T)
r <- raster(CurrTemp)

extent(r) <- c(-3950000, 3950000, -3950000, 4350000)
crs(r) <- "+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-70 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs "
# writeRaster(r, 'my_asi-s6250-20030214-v5.tif')
```

The "other hdf" file has longitude / latitude values for the cells, but that is not what you are after as the data do not have a lon/lat coordinate reference system.